# Rearrange xml node in xml file

Tags: c#, xml, xml-parsing

I have xml file like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TestSuite name="TestSuite1" UID="0" State="Indeterminate">
  <TestCase name="TestCase1" UID="1" State="Indeterminate" DataSourceId="1">
    <TestModule name="1" State="Unchecked" UID="1">
    </TestModule>
    <TestModule name="2" State="Unchecked" UID="2">
    </TestModule>
    <TestModule name="3" State="Unchecked" UID="3">
    </TestModule>
  </TestCase>
  <TestCase name="TestCase2" UID="33" State="Indeterminate" DataSourceId="1">
    <TestModule name="4" State="Unchecked" UID="4">
    </TestModule>
    <TestModule name="5" State="Unchecked" UID="5">
    </TestModule>
    <TestModule name="6" State="Unchecked" UID="6">
    </TestModule>
  </TestCase>
</TestSuite>
```

I have to remove `TestModule name="3"` to above or below `TestModule name="1"` node.

Updated file will be like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TestSuite name="TestSuite1" UID="0" State="Indeterminate">
  <TestCase name="TestCase1" UID="1" State="Indeterminate" DataSourceId="1">
    <TestModule name="3" State="Unchecked" UID="4bdb93ca-4f76-4709-ab88-13297def827b">
    </TestModule>
    <TestModule name="1" State="Unchecked" UID="5aa80bb6-9616-458c-b095-d6a0edbaf95b">
    </TestModule>
    <TestModule name="2" State="Unchecked" UID="2">
    </TestModule>
  </TestCase>
</TestSuite>
```

I have written below code for that

```
XmlDocument xDoc = new XmlDocument();
xDoc.Load(Path.Combine(@"D:\Test Suite\TestSuite.xml"));

///////////////////
XmlNode l_NodeToAppend = null;
foreach (XmlNode i in e.SourceModels)
{
    l_NodeToAppend = xDoc.SelectSingleNode(String.Format("//*[@UID='{0}']", ((XmlNode)i).Attributes["UID"].Value));//1
    if (l_NodeToAppend != null)
        break;
}

XmlNode l_targteNode = xDoc.SelectSingleNode(String.Format("//*[@UID='{0}']", ((XmlNode)e.TargetModel).Attributes["UID"].Value));//3

bool flag = false;
l_NodeToAppend.InsertBefore(l_NodeToAppend, l_targteNode);
```

It is giving error "Cannot insert a node or any ancestor of that node as a child of itself."

Comment: Last `TestModule` node in each `TestCase` node must be the first node?

Comment: that should decide at run time which node be append first or last user will decide

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must specify concrete node name as `TestModule`.

```
XmlNode l_NodeToAppend = null;
foreach (XmlNode i in e.SourceModels)
{
    l_NodeToAppend = xDoc.SelectSingleNode(string.Format("//TestModule[@UID='{0}']", i.Attributes["UID"].Value));
    if (l_NodeToAppend != null)
        break;
}

XmlNode l_targetNode = xDoc.SelectSingleNode(string.Format("//TestModule[@UID='{0}']", e.TargetModel.Attributes["UID"].Value));

l_targetNode.ParentNode.InsertBefore(l_NodeToAppend, l_targetNode);
```

And as already mentioned in another answer, you need to use the parent node

Comment: At runtime i have to rearrange there are multiple tescase node inside multiple testmodules

Answer (score 1):

This worked.
The Xpath expressions must use the "name" attribute, since these children don't have numeric UID.
Also the InsertBefore is executed from the parent of the children, first argument is the child to be rearranged, second argument is the child used as a reference for the rearrangement.

```
        XmlNode l_NodeToAppend = l_NodeToAppend = xDoc.SelectSingleNode(String.Format("//*[@name='{0}']", 1));//1

        XmlNode l_targteNode = xDoc.SelectSingleNode(String.Format("//*[@name='{0}']", 3));//3

        bool flag = false;
        l_NodeToAppend.ParentNode.InsertBefore(l_targteNode,l_NodeToAppend);
```

Comment: Some explanation in addition to the code would made this answer more useful to other users.